# Printing Ubuntu source code

Tags: printing, source-code

Newbie reading Ubuntu Unleashed 18.04 book & DVD. I want to print out the source code. Ubuntu Unleashed, page 30, states 55 million lines of code in C and 5 million in C++.

One member responded by pointing out I need to access the list of program names and pick one I am interested in and print it out.   There are over 2500 program names.

Specific questions:

1. I need to know how to access the list of program names.

   self-answered: run Terminal, enter `apt` and return, read printout of info, enter `apt list` and return.   All program names displayed.
2. I need to know the boot up program name order the computer uses on start up.
3. I need to know how to print out a program.

I found the internal program terminal access.

I tried entering the information provided by 2 members to list the program names, but as a newbee I must be missing something since I get an error.

Comment: Why do you want do this?

Comment: Printing out 60 Million lines of C and C++ source would take about 1,200,000 pages, and be unreadable. Save the Trees!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to print out the Ubuntu source code.

First of all, you don't really want to do this. It's huge, and computer code on paper is worthless. It's hard to change, and hard to jump around in.

Second, it's not like a book. It has various components, that together make the system work. This includes the kernel, which you hardly interface with at all, the desktop environment that you actually interface daily, and so on.

To get the source for a package, simply run `apt-get source packagename`, e.g. `apt-get source pidgin`. This will give you a folder in the format of `packagename-version/`, which contains all the source code files. The number of files is likely to be in the hundreds to thousands for most packages. Pidgin for instance has 2510 files.

So I suggest focusing on packages that interest you.

Answer (score 0):

These tools will help you download the source of any package.

```
# pkg        command
devscripts: /usr/bin/dget
apt:        /usr/bin/apt-get
```